# Count the number of rows where date range is within another date range

Tags: google-sheets

I recently asked a different question that was similar but I'm not able to map that answer to my actual need.

| Range A | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 Jan 2023 | 31 Mar 2023 |

| Test Ranges | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 Feb 2023 | 15 Feb 2023 |
| B | 15 Mar 2023 | 30 Jun 2023 |
| C | 15 Dec 2022 | 15 Jan 2023 |
| D | 1 Jun 2023 | 30 Jun 2023 |

Create a formula that counts the Test Range ROWS and include them if their range is at least partially part of RANGE A:

Ranges A, B and C are within Range A so the answer is:

**3**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TM7CrZfAevGBGUrxaWzpab7ybl6SsNdCI2c0G61VhJE/edit#gid=0

EDIT:  The answer should be able to handle a variable number of TEST RANGES - something like "D2:D", and if the rows below are empty they would be ignored.

Comment: Another approach: `=sum(map(B7:B,C7:C,lambda(start_,end_,countifs(start_,"<="&C3,end_,">="&B3))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following f

```
=SUM(MAP(B7:B15,C7:C15,
LAMBDA(bbb,ccc,IF(bbb="","",
      IF(AND(OR(B3<=bbb,B3<=ccc),OR(ccc<=$C$3,bbb<=$C$3))=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))*1)))
```

**OR**

```
=SUM(INDEX(IF(B7:B15="","", 
       IF((B7:B15>=$B$3)*(B7:B15<=$C$3)+(C7:C15>=$B$3)*(C7:C15<=$C$3)>0,TRUE,FALSE)*1)))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=SUM(MAP(INDEX((B7:B10>=B3)*(B7:B10<=C3)),INDEX((C7:C10>=B3)*(C7:C10<=C3)),LAMBDA(x,y,--OR(x,y))))
```

Simplified formula-

```
=SUM(INDEX(--(((B7:B10>=B3)*(B7:B10<=C3)+(C7:C10>=B3)*(C7:C10<=C3))>0)))
```

[image]